# Android:map not working on 2.2.1

Tags: android, google-maps

I am making an app in which i have to current position of individual on map but the map is not working properly on 2.2.1 .Any help will be appreciated.
Why this cross sign are coming?I mean to say how to remove this "X" sign.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chexk your zoom level as well as view (Satellite or StreetView). you might be doing something wrong in any of these 2 aspect.

Comment: What probably happens is that he enabled Satellite and Map view at the same time, as I specify on the link to a question with the same topic.